# making barplot for distribution of a continuous variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a barplot to visualize distribution of continuous variable, e.g. price distribution for listing price. 
I generated some sample data and make a barplot with ggplot2.

```
a<- rnorm (100, 1000, 1000)
d <- as.data.frame(a)
d <-d %>%  mutate(b=cut(a, breaks=seq(min(a),max(a), 500))) %>% 
    group_by(b) %>% summarize(count=n())
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=b, y=count)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
    theme (axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, size=5, face='bold'))
```

[image]

My question is

- how can I format the xaxis label so that, for example, 1.22e+03 becomes 1220.
- why the last bin becomes NA?

I know I can just use geom_histogram for this data. But I just want to have some flexibility to cut the continuous variable into bins for some highly skewed data.
Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a bar plot or a histogram? If you skip your mutate step, you could just do `ggplot(d) + geom_histogram(aes(a))` Otherwise you're going to have to get the `labels=` curing `cut()` if you want to make them "pretty".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both issues are about `cut()`. You should read `?cut`

To avoid scientific notations in the classes labels, use the argument `dig.lab`. In your example, `cut(a, breaks=seq(min(a),max(a), 500), dig.lab = 6L)` seems to be enough.

`NA`s appear for two reasons linked to your `breaks` argument. First, by default, the first break is excluded from `cut()`, so that the observation where `a == min(a)` will be `NA`. To overcome this, use `include.lowest = TRUE`.

Finally, your highest values will be ignored because `seq(min(a), max(a), 500)` produces a vector that stops at the last multiple of 500 **before `max(a)`** and therefore does not include `max(a)`. To overcome this, you need to make sure the second argument of seq is the first multiple of 500 after `max(a)`, like `ceiling(max(a) / 500) * 500`.

Therefore, this should work:

```
d <-d %>%  
  mutate(b=cut(a, breaks=seq(min(a), ceiling(max(a) / 500) * 500, 500), 
               include.lowest = TRUE, 
               dig.lab = 6L)) %>% 
  group_by(b) %>% summarize(count=n())
```

Comment: Very clear explanation! Very nice! Thank you!! @scoa